# What is this method of hiding a class called?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've implemented a library that exposes a function `speach()` to create an object with specific public API functions. The functions proxy to an internal object `class Speach` which I don't expose to the end-user so the implementation details cannot be touched. I can change implementation details later as long as I continue to support the publicly exposed API.

Is there a name for this pattern?

```js
class Speach {
  constructor() {
    // ...
  }

  browserSupportsFeature() {}

  loadAPI() {}

  voice(name) {
    // ...
  }

  speak(textToSpeak) {
    // ...
  }

  then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
    // ...
  }
}

const speach = () => {
  const speach = new Speach();
  return {
    voice(name) {
      speach.voice(name);
      return this;
    },
    speak(textToSpeak) {
      speach.speak(textToSpeak);
      return this;
    },
    then(thenable) {
      speach.then(thenable);
      return this;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: If you ignore the whole class part and just focus on exposing public method will hiding the implementation details, that's the module pattern

Comment: Yes! Thank you @Axnyff, I'm cross-posting this as an answer.

Comment: I would call it `Encapsulation` but overall this pattern seems to be a bad workaround, as I believe you could achieve this by using simple inheritance. There's no need to "Hide" functionality if your `base class` only exposes the methods that you need. the `child class` then could extend `Speach` with the methods it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricting access to variables by limiting their scope inside a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is called information hiding.

This implementation is basically the [the Module pattern](https://coryrylan.com/blog/javascript-module-pattern-basics).

Comment: Why doing so in such a verbose way? Instead of just `module.exports = new Speach()`?

Comment: @RenatoGama I intended to expose a specific public API and not export the implementation of the `class Speach`, in case I want to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Abstraction.

Abstraction is when you hide implementation details and only expose the interface to the client. The developer can change the underlying implementation as they please as long as the outside interface stays the same.

Comment: In my opinion, the pattern used is more like `encapsulation` as the `speach` hides some functionality of the class, rather than provide an abstraction of `Speach`

Comment: Encapsulation is used for hide the code and data in a single unit to protect the data from the outside the world. Abstraction refers to showing only the necessary details to the intended user.

Comment: Indeed, however in `Speach` the methods are still exposed, whilst `speach` is *hidding* the other methods by wrapping the Implementation of the class in other methods. Overall, this should be solved with Inheritance.